# Martin Landau: RIP

Tags: discussion, in-memoriam

Sadly, I wish to mark the passing of **[Martin Landau](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martin_Landau)** with extremely fond memories of Commander Koenig.

[image]

Whilst he has provided many enjoyable performances over his 89 years, his contribution to sci-fi in Space 1999 will remain one of my childhood favourites.

Comment: Martin Landau playing Bela Lugosi playing Dracula was amazing to behold.

Answer (score 2):

It is interesting how he and Leonard Nimoy had similar careers -- similar-looking, sounding actors with roles on similar shows. I think in one case they played the same character -- Mission Impossible, right?